# How can I send the JSON coming from a POST request to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch-api

I have a node server running with express which listens to incoming requests. I am rendering an HTML file which I would like to update when I receive a GET request in my server. However, the data that is sent to my server is sent by an API when an external event happen (asynchronously). I don't know how to update the HTML file I'm serving with the JSON content of the incoming request. Particularly, I am trying to replace the `inner.HTML` content of the incoming class as you can see in my code.

I have tried to use the fetch API on the client side to make a request to the server to retrieve this data, but it doesn't seem to work.

Server.js

```
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const port = 3000;

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log('App listening on port ${port}'));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', ejs.renderFile);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true}));



app.get (‘/incoming', (req,res)=>{

  const { status} = req.url;

  res.json(status);
  console.log(status);

})
```

Client.js

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/incoming').then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(response => {
  document.getElementById("dlr").innerHTML = response
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

index.html

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-layout/1.1.1/css-layout.js" />
  <title>Node SMS Texting</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Text API</h2>
    <input type="sender" name="from" id="from" placeholder="Enter sender ID ...">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Send Text" class="button button-primary">
    <p class="response"></p>
    <p class="incoming"></p>
  </div>

  <script src="js/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I get the result logged in the console as per my `console.log` in the server side, but the client doesn't receive anything. This is the `console.log`

> /incoming?user=A&to=Me&code=21404&Id=150000001A01F77B&&timestamp=2019-04-08+15%3A57%3A15&timestamp=1554739095&nonce=59167e2f-654c-4dd5-b236-bff9ac97f917

The only thing I see happening on the client side is /incoming set as text  set under the `incoming.innerhtml` class, but not the content of the GET request sent to my server.

Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a GET request to a POST endpoint. This you can fix by passing a body and a method in your fetch on client side. Also, you should handle the response as it comes back. Rewrite your fetch to something like this.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/incoming', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then(response => {
  document.getElementById("incoming").innerHTML = response
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
```

Comment: Hi Imre, I really appreciate your quick response here. It makes total sense what you say. However, I don't know what I would need to pass in the body. I only need to receive incoming data from the server, so I wouldn't really need to pass anything to the server. Could you please shed some light here? Regards,

Comment: Hi Javilondo, in that case, you are using the wrong method in express. Typically, you use POST if you want to send some data to your server, for example, a record to add in the database. If you just want to retrieve data, you use GET. So update your express app to `app.get`.

Comment: Hi Imre, thanks for getting back to me. Indeed, I've tried both, but it seems that I can't access the data in the client. Let me update the post above so that you can see what I currently have.

Comment: If you visit http://localhost:3000/incoming in the browser. Do you see your data?

Comment: Actually, no. I just see my data when I log it from the server side i,e. when it comes to the server. If I go to localhost:3000/incoming it's registered as another GET request, but the data is not showing. This data comes from an external API when an external event happens.